# how to apply tooltip for each datalist option element in Semantic UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

```
import { Input } from 'semantic-ui-react';

  <div>
    <Input list='lists' placeholder='Choose language...' />
    <datalist id='lists'>
      <option value='brandname' />
      <option value='company' />
      <option value='count' />
    </datalist>
  </div>
```

I'm following official documentation  of Semantic UI React for select an  option i want to apply the tooltip for each option in right side

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
import { Popup } from 'semantic-ui-react';


  <div>
    <Input list='lists' placeholder='Choose language...' />
    <datalist id='lists'>
      <Popup content='This is the brand name' trigger={<option value='brandname' />} />
    </datalist>
  </div>
```

Apply `Popup` for all your `option` elements.

[Documentation](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup/#types-popup)